# Which dataset is best for storing complex data structure? Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, data-structures

I have the following data structure:

One sample contains 5 vectors. In all the vectors there are elements from the same classes but the classes are different between the vectors. These vectors are really big with thousands of elements.
I usually have several (5-10) samples.

At the moment I have a vector for every sample what contains the vectors of the classes. And I store the vectors of the samples in a vector so I can manage all the samples at once.

I use vector cause while filling my dataset I use `.append()`. But later on I won't change the data just iterate through and analyze it.

My problem is with memory. Now the dataset eats a lot of it. So some optimization would be great.

> That's why I ask if there is a better way to store this dataset?

I've heard that array is better if I don't change my data. Is it worth maybe to convert everything to array after loaded them as vector? 
What do you recommend?

For example, I show a dataset below similar to mine:

```
class van:
    #some data
    pass;
class bus:
    #some more data
    pass;
class motorcycle:
    #something else
    pass;

all_data = []
for i in range(7):
    vans = [van() for i in range(5000)]
    buses = [bus() for i in range(2000)]
    mcycles = [motorcycle() for i in range(3000)]
    dataset = [vans, buses, mcycles]
    all_data.append(dataset)
```

Comment: Why don’t you use numpy arrays? Also if you really need classes you might want to use `__slots__` to define the list of attributs your class can have. This will reduce memory consumption.

Comment: Is `vans` the same for every `i`?

Comment: No `vans` are not the same it's just for the example

Comment: `__slots__` helped quite much! Around 20% less memory usage. Thanks @Y0da

Comment: @CsengerKovácsházi will make an answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you need to keep the class structure, you can have a drastic improvement of the memory consumption just by using `__slots__`. When a new object will be created, only attribute defined in this list will be allowed. But this is more efficient. Checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/472000/6522112).

Another approach would be to use [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.rec.html) from numpy. But this depends on the exact nature of your data.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep your current code intact (minimizing work), you may consider replacing lists with [lazylist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lazylist). [lazylist@github](https://github.com/dahlia/lazylist)